# sql sub query

Tags: sql

Hi I need a small help regarding writing a simple query. I want to display results based on max number of employees in a dept.

Here is my table

```
empid           dept           sal
emp001          d001           10000
emp002          d001           10000
emp003          d002           20000
emp004          d001           10000
emp005          d003            5000
emp006          d003            5000
```

Expected result

```
empid         dept           sal
emp001         d001           10000
emp002         d001           10000
emp004         d001           10000
emp005         d003            5000
emp006         d003            5000
emp003         d002           20000
```

so dept1 contains 3 employees so it should come first and dept3 contains 2 employees so it will come next and so on

Thanks in advance,

Nagu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried this in MySQL, and with this query:

> SELECT e1. * , count( e2.empid ) AS c
>   FROM `employees` e1 LEFT JOIN
>   employees e2 ON e1.dept = e2.dept
>   GROUP BY e1.empid ORDER BY c DESC

I got this result:

```
empid   dept    sal     c
emp001  d001    10000   3
emp004  d001    10000   3
emp002  d001    10000   3
emp006  d003    5000    2
emp005  d003    5000    2
emp003  d002    20000   1
```

And then you could of course sort on empid to get the emp002 before the emp004 etc :)

Edit: A better MySQL query would be with not selecting * elements and escaping all table and field names with backticks, something like this:

> SELECT `e1`.`empid`, `e1`.`dept`,
>   `e1`.`sal`, COUNT(`e2`.`empid`) AS `c`
>   FROM `employees` `e1` LEFT JOIN
>   `employees` `e2` ON `e1`.`dept` =
>   `e2`.`dept` GROUP BY `e1`.`empid`
>   ORDER BY `c` DESC, `e1`.`empid`

Comment: This will only work on MySQL, because you're grouping on e1.empid and selecting e1.*

Answer (score 3):

The answer hardly depends on your DBMS !
With Oracle 8+ you can use analytic functions :

```
select empid, dept, sal
from MyTable
order by count(empid) over (partition by dept) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the headcount per department in a join, and then order by that:

```
select e.empid, e.dept e.sal
from employees e
inner join (
    select dept, total = count(*)
    from employees
    group by dept
) headcount hc on hc.dept = e.dept
order by hc.total desc, e.dept, e.sal
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a database avaiable to test this on, but try giving this a whirl:

```
SELECT empid, dept, sal
  FROM emp_table
  JOIN
  (SELECT COUNT(empid) [emp_count], dept
     FROM emp_table
     GROUP BY dept
  ) count_table
  ON emp_table.dept = count_table.dept
  ORDER BY
    emp_count DESC
    , empid ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

> The answer hardly depends on your DBMS ! With Oracle 8+ you can use analytic functions :

The same query works with SQL Server 2005+

There is another solution that gives same result and almost the same execution plan:

```
;With DeptCount as 
( Select dept, count(empid) as cnt
    from employees
   group by dept
)
Select e.empid, e.dept e.sal
  From employees e
 Inner Join DeptCount c  
         on e.dept=c.dept
 Order By c.cnt DESC, e.empid ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Version without CTE:

```
Select e.empid, e.dept e.sal
  From employees e
 Inner Join ( Select dept, count(empid) as cnt
                from employees
               group by dept
            )  c on e.dept=c.dept
 Order By c.cnt DESC, e.empid ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what you want exactly, but this query gives you the number of employees per dept.

```
SELECT dept, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY dept
```

Best Regards

Comment: Yeah, but that's not what he asked for.